# Fetch Parse Data based on Array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, parse-platform, tableview, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController.

I also have an array of numbers in a randomly generated order, from 1 to the Parse class count.

In Parse, each object in the class is assigned a number (1,2 ,3, etc.)

I want to fetch objects from this class in Parse to table view cells,and the order depends on the order of the array.

For example, my array would be [3, 2, 5, 1, 4]

I want to query where key "number" is equal to those numbers, in that order..

So far I have this:

```
// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery{

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Stores")

    for i in 1...10 {
    query.whereKey("number", equalTo: numArray[i])
    }

    return query
 }
```

and

```
//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ExploreCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = ExploreCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }
```

however, whenever i run, it only grabs information from 1 objects. My table view only has 1 cell that grabbed data.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's Swift Code (I actually don't know Swift).

Anyway I don't see the need to (try to) query the objects in the order you want from array. Actually using `query.whereKey` more times you will just use the last one.

What you should do, is actually query the objects and then sort them (unless you want an ascending/descending order).

Also keep in mind that a Parse Query is asynchronous so probably structuring the function like you did won't work like you want.

EDIT: This is the kind of code you may want to use:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        println(object.objectId)
      }
    } 
} else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

The `objects` variable is the array you want to sort.

The [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries) has been always useful to me to actually understand better Parse

Comment: Good point, i realized that it would only take the last one. Now I'm trying to figure out how to append the objects to an array, and shuffle them. Any chance you know how I can start?

Comment: I edited the answer. That's an example of how you can actually get an array of objects from making a query. After you have the array, it should be easy for you to sort it.